# What's a better replacement for the word "enemy"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

What's a better replacement for the word *enemy*? I'm not simply looking for a synonym, I'm looking for one that fits this context:

> When you don't know how to use your firearm, you could essentially become the **attacker**.

My superior has been slightly vague, saying he'd like the word *attacker* changed to something else, as it doesn't "sound right." (His suggestion was, 'You become the danger', but in my opinion that's not much better.)

The synonyms I found for *attacker* didn't fit very well, so I'm trying to find another way to express this thought.

Comment: "...it doesn't sound--" what? What exactly are you asking about? "You could essentially become the attacker" doesn't have the same register as "you become the danger". What synonyms did you find that should be discounted?

Comment: I'd suggest *threat*.

Comment: That's great Jim, thank you. Yes Andrew, _danger_ wasn't the best suggestion he could have given me.

Comment: "Threat" is an excellent term given the context.

Comment: I'd skip from a single word to: "become part of the problem".

Answer (score 5):

When you don't know how to use your firearm, you become *a menace*.

As used here, [*menace*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/menace) is a noun meaning:

> A person or thing that is likely to cause harm; a threat or danger

Answer (score 4):

I can see how your superior officer reached that conclusion. Not knowing your weapon can lead to accidents and "friendly-fire" losses. You do become a danger. I rather like *enemy* because in such incidents you are effectively the enemy. However, it's a bit of work to make the connection.

Perhaps it could be made explicit?

> When you don't know how to use your firearm, the risk of friendly fire could turn you into the enemy.

Answer (score 4):

In this case I think the word "Threat" might fit best, it indicates that one would be creating a danger while remaining unspecific on the level of intent and exact nature of the threat. It also focuses on what others would feel under the situation which seems apt here.

Answer (score 3):

When you don't know how to use your firearm, you could essentially become the:

> [**hazard**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard) (Wikipedia)
>   A hazard is a situation that poses a level of threat to life, health, property, or environment. Most hazards are dormant or potential, with only a theoretical risk of harm; however, once a hazard becomes "active", it can create an emergency situation.

Answer (score 3):

> When you don't know how to use your firearm, you essentially ***_*__*_*_**.

I would additionally suggest:

- *become a [liability](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/liability)* (used in the sense that if you lose control, you become a liability)
- *put everybody at risk*
- *[endanger](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/endanger) everybody around you*
- *become your own/biggest enemy*
- *are a hindrance*

Comment: I don't necessarily like "hindrance", but I think "liability" is a decent suggestion. I'm surprised this got downvoted. Also, as a variant of one of your answers, one might also consider, "When you don't know how to use your firearm, you put everyone at risk – including yourself."

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that *You become the **danger*** is a piss-poor, piss-rotten (distasteful or unpleasant), piss-weak (pathetic), or piss-awful (very unpleasant) substitution for *You become the **enemy***.

I was thinking of ***foe***, ***adversary***, and ***antagonist***, but I think I prefer ***enemy*** here. ***Threat*** is also a good suggestion. Miles above ***danger***.

Comment: Actually, in the context provided, I think I'd opt for _"You become the danger"_ before _"You become the attacker."_ We're in agreement, though, that _threat_ is superior to either of those.